# problems installing qgis 2.0 Add-ons

Tags: qgis-plugins

I have installed qgis 2.0, I need to install add-ons and NEXT I get the error 'The supplement package decompression failed. probably is broken or missing in the repository. might also want to make sure you have write permission to the plugin directory:
/ home/cordero/.qgis2 / / python / plugins "I searched the file path indicated by the error but apparently I have not the directory, and uninstall and reinstall qgis on my pc but the problem persists[image]

Comment: You most likely have the folder (QGIS stores its configuration there) as it is a hidden folder on Linux systems. Just go into `/home/cordero` and press CTRL+H to make hidden objects visible. Alternatively look into your filebrowsers options